# How do I use JQuery to get the attribute of a selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="hello">
    <option data-title="foo" value="1" selected="selected">Abcdefg</option
</select>
```

To get the value of the selection, I usually do this:

```
$("#hello").val(); // returns 1
```

But what if I want to get the data-title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('#hello option:selected').data('title');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('option:selected', '#hello').attr('data-title');
```

**Update**

While the above aproach *works*, as others have stated the preferable way to handle this is with the [data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
$('option:selected', '#hello').data('title');
```

**Update 2**

In researching this further I found [this page](http://lookfirst.com/2011/12/dont-use-jquery-data-method-use-attr.html) which explains why using `attr` is preferable, and outlines cases where `data` misbehaves.

**Update 3**

[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/2) demonstrates that `attr` is massively (80% in my tests) faster than using `data`.  I'm still attempting to find canonical documentation on why, or if using `data` is preferable to using `attr`.

Comment: Geez, thanks to two downvoters with no comments/feedback

Comment: You used `.attr()` to fetch DOM Data, don't. There is an API for that.

Comment: @Chad Does this approach not work?

Comment: Didn't say it didn't work, I said you shouldn't do it. There is an API for that. If I set a data property pragmatically, you won't be able to get it with `.attr()`, but `.data()` will always work.

Comment: @Chad maybe read the FAQ on downvoting, this answer hardly deserves it. Your feedback is useful to me, but my answer isn't inherently wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @Chad - I have had instances were `.data` hasn't brought the value back but `.attr` has. Although `data` may be preferred, I agree with Madbreaks that the answer shouldn't be downvoted if he originally used `attr` and achieves the same result.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Does the jQuery `data` approach fail if it itself wasn't used to set the data on the element, I wonder?  In other words, if I arbitrarily generate a `<div data-title="blah"></div>`, might that prevent jQuery from querying the element via `data()`?

Comment: @DarrenDavies I would love to see an example of that, because if it is happening then it was a bug. It is not only bad practice to use `.attr` for this it will teach people landing here later a practice that is *incorrect* for many use-cases. @Madbreaks no, I use jQuery to get data attributes I manually specify in HTML all the time.

Comment: @Chad: Unless you have specific need to have the `data-` attribute value imported into jQuery's proprietary `.data()` system, there absolutely nothing "bad" about using `.attr()`. Using `.data()` is more expensive, and you're gaining nothing except additional memory overhead if there's no plan to actually use it within jQuery's data cache. To be clear, jQuery does not use the `dataset` API for `data-` attributes. If we're going to talk about a proper API, *that* would be the one to use, though older browsers don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = $('#hello').find(':selected').data('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
$('#hello :selected').data('title');
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of where using `attr` doesn't work?  Or is *"incorrect for many use cases"*? Genuinely interested.  Also would be interested to see where that's doc'd.

Comment: I mentioned it in my other post, if you add it as a dynamic property. Attr doesn't work.

Comment: Like: set it with `$('#id').data('title', 'some data');` and then try to get it with `$('#id').attr('data-title');` and it will not work. attr will only work for 1 way you can put data on an element, but .data will work for *any* way that DOM data can be added.